# Identifying duplicates in Excel across multiple sheets in the same column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates, conditional-formatting

I wasn't sure if this was more of a SuperUser question, but I had seen similar questions here, so I thought I'd give this a try.  Apologies if this is misplaced!

I am using an Excel spreadsheet to track dozens of email inquiries, and currently have two sheets.  I input data in the first sheet and then do a mail merge to send out intro emails in response to the inquiries.  After the mail merge, I move that data to the second sheet for the next step.

*What I'd like to do* is identify duplicate entries as I'm entering new data in the first sheet, because sometimes people will send multiple inquiries, and I don't want to send multiple intro emails.  However, attempts to apply conditional formatting to more than one sheet have consistently failed!  In fact, if I try, for example, to enter "=Sheet1!$C:$C,Sheet2!$C:$C" as the range (Email is in column C), it just ignores what I wrote and changes it back to whatever the previous selection was.  I also tried naming the ranges, but that didn't seem to work either.

I'm not a newbie with Excel, but I'm not especially experienced either, so I figure there's something simple I'm missing; but several Google searches with various keywords have all been fruitless.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think I nearly have it.  In Excel 2010, I choose the row in the first sheet, then on the Home tab go to Conditional Formatting > New Rule.  Then I choose "Use a formula to determine which cells to format".  For the formula, I use what @WorkSmarter suggested (thank you!) -- =IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$C:$C,C1),TRUE,FALSE) -- and choose a red background for Format.  It then only highlights entries in the same row on the second sheet -- yay!  The only thing is... it's highlighting the header row, too!  How can I select an entire row *except* the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely doable.  I created a helper column to identify duplicate email entries in the other spreadsheet.  Note: Started with Sheet1!C2 to reflect title i.e. "Email" in first row.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!$C:$C,Sheet1!C2),TRUE,FALSE)
```

---

**Example of Input Data Worksheet**

[image]

---

**Example of Post Mail Merge Worksheet**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Violet if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I appreciate your help.  This is not quite how I wanted to do it, however.  I'd really prefer to use conditional formatting to accomplish this.  Is there some way to simply highlight a duplicate cell as I've described, so I can then decide on the appropriate action myself?  Simply removing the duplicate may not always be the action I would like to take.

Comment: "Simply removing the duplicates may not always be the action I would like to take".  The code provided indicates which emails are duplicates. No additional action is taken by the code.  The second image represents the range, used for comparison. If an email is present in both images, then it will display "True" in the duplicate column, else it will display "False".